# html element alignment with float:left and float:right

Tags: html, css

This is a very basic html-css query that I often encounter. Most times, I find the solution some way or the other, but am interested to know the reason of this unexpected behavior(as per me) of UI.

Please have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yaRU/

```
<div > //float left
  Sometext <span> text<.span>//float:right
<div>
```

the right floated text moves to the next line though there is a lot of width available in my line. Ideally as per me, the text should appear side by side with float:left as left side, and float:right at right side within the div.

This cant be a complex issue, so is there something very common I do not get here?

Comment: Are you floating the containing div left for any particular reason? Doing so shrinks the width to match its content.

Comment: floating it left to make all its child elements float left automatically, unless specified. Is that not the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

Put the floated item first. The floats are nested inside of each-other, so they won't affect each-other. Floating an element automatically changes it display:block;

Comment: Right Matthew. Thanks for the response, I t works that way. My question here is if the floated item comes after the text, the element should remain at rightmost position in the same line, however, it moves to the next line here. I get the reason from your answer that because the float converts it to div, it moves to the next line. Is it? So now the question becomes for <div1> <div2>  A<div3> B </div3> </div2> </div1>, should A and B not appear in the same line as they both are nested under the same div?

Comment: @user1242321: To paraphrase... Inside a container, the HTML for all floated content should appear before any non-floated content. Or it may not behave as you'd expect.

Comment: See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEbr2/ if i remove the float:left from div1 everything appears in one line; however if i add the same, it starts appearing in the next line.

Comment: I don't see what you are describing, but it could be that you simply need to add a width to the outer floated DIV. It's possible that once you float the parent element, it is no longer being sized large enough to hold all the content on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a couple things going on. Since the wrap is `float:left`, it switches to a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting). It looks like the issue is that the whitespace that comes after the text (just before the nested float) is considered to be trailing since there is nothing is in the flow after it. So the width of the parent does not take into account the space, even though it *does* take up space when the layout is rendered as you can see in the html.

Removing the trailing space brings the X back onto the same line as the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/2yaRU/8/

If you want a space after the text, you should add a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) to the html instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/2yaRU/9/